# Remove html tags from Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I want to get a simple HTML form:

```
<form method="post"> 
<input type="text" name="question" id="question" value="" size="50%">
<input type="submit" name="ask" id="ask" value="Ask">
</form>
```

What I get with Zend Framework is:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action=""> 
<dt id="question-label">&#160;</dt> 
<dd id="question-element"> 
<input type="text" name="question" id="question" value="" size="50%"></dd> 
<dt id="ask-label">&#160;</dt><dd id="ask-element"> 
<input type="submit" name="ask" id="ask" value="Ask"></dd>
</form>
```

How can I remove unwanted html tags (dd, dt)?

Answer (score 3):

I found similar question, and answer there lead me to using following solution (which works for me):

```
$form->setElementDecorators(array('ViewHelper','Errors'));
```

Comment: You also need to use `$form->setDecorators('FormElements', 'Form');` to remove the DL tag.

Comment: whit some changes use this : $this->setDecorators(array('FormElements', 'Form'));

Answer (score 0):

You can use ->removeDecorator(“DtDdWrapper”); to remove the dt and dd wrappers.

Comment: I have tried using $form->removeDecorator(“DtDdWrapper”); but this had no effect.

Comment: @kklobucki: You should use it on the Zend_Form_Element.

Answer (score 0):

Full control over the output of a form without circumventing the Form Logic / filtering / validation
`The View:`

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->form->getAction(); ?>" method="<?php echo $this->form->getMethod(); ?>">

    <!-- Errors For question field-->
    <?php echo (NULL != ($errors = $this->form->getElement('question')->getMessages()) ? $this->formErrors($errors) : ''); ?>

    <!-- question field -->
    <?php echo $this->form->getElement('question')->renderViewHelper(); ?>

    <!-- Submit Field -->
    <?php echo $this->form->getElement('submit')->renderViewHelper(); ?>
</form>
```

End

`The Form`

```
<?php
class Form_Question extends Zend_Form
{
public function init()
{
    $this->setMethod(self::METHOD_POST);

    $element = $this->createElement('text', 'question');
    $element->setLabel('Question');
    $element->setRequired(TRUE);
    $element->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
    $element->setAttrib('class', 'text');
    $this->addElement($element);

    $element = $this->createElement('submit', 'submit');
    $element->setLabel('Submit');
    $element->setRequired(TRUE);
    $element->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
    $element->removeDecorator('label');
    $this->addElement($element);
}
}
```

end form

`the controller action`

```
    public function questionAction()
{
    $form = new Form_Question();

    if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
        if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()))
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_helper->FlashMessenger(array('error' => "Errors! Correct the errors in the form below"));
        }
    }

    $this->view->assign('form', $form);
}
```

end controller action